# Inactive device token, urbanairship, cordova, ios

Tags: iphone, cordova, urbanairship.com

I am developing an app using cordova. For push notification, I am integration urbanairship. The device is getting registered successfully but the status of device token gets inactive.

I have created both development and production profiles but am unable to get device registered as active.

Can anyone help me out plz?

Comment: Where you see the status of that device? I never used urbanairship ... try to implement such things on your own in my opinion. Did you try so send a Push Message? What is happening on the Device? Is it triggerd if the app is in foreground?

Comment: You can see status of device token using urbanairship console, and yes  I have sent Push Message, It is not received on device whether the app was on foreground or background.

Comment: I found a answer [here](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/69169613-Inactive-Device-Tokens), and I am registering the device in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function within appDelegate. But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are times during development or perhaps you’ve launched your app to the app store and you see either your token or messages of inactive tokens in your UA application. Device token as inactive when one of three things happen:

> 1. Apple tells us that the application has been uninstalled via the feedback service, which we check on a regular basis.
> 2. Apple rejected the device token for your app upon receipt of the notification at their servers
> 3. explicit delete call on the device token, which marks it as inactive and clears the alias and any associated tags.
> 4. If the device token was created when iOS 6 was installed, and the device has since updated to iOS 7, the old device token is eventually
>      rejected by Apple because the device now has a new, app-specific iOS 7
>      device token.

In any case, applications should expect and handle inactive device tokens properly. do one of the following:

> 1. Register the device token every time the application is opened,
> 2. Use feedback API regularly, store inactivated device tokens in your own database, and send registrations when the device token becomes
>      active again

Thank you. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Answer (score 0):

If the device token is immediately inactive then it's a good sign that you've mixed your development and production environments.  Remember, production certificates need to line up with production applications, from Apple all the way to Urban Airship. Likewise with development.  If a development device token attempts to register as a production application, Apple will reject it and Urban Airship will mark it as inactive.

Here's another UA support article on how to create the appropriate type of application:
https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/69534443-Urban-Airship-Development-vs-Production-Apps

Comment: Yes it immediately inactive, but development and production environments and certificates are seems to be in order.